# if a character, lets say '9', I minus '0', and I use is digit on the result, do I get true or false

Tags: c++

if a character, lets say '9', I minus '0', and I use is digit on the result, do I get true or false

I was using leetcode to try atoi and a basic concept question on the function isdigit stuck me.

```cpp
if(isdigit(str[i]-'0')==false){
    return str[i]-'0';
    break;
}
```

Input:
"42"
Output:
4
Expected:
42

I'm wondering if isdigit function will return true if str[i] is equal to char'0'

Answer (score 3):

No `isdigit` operates on characters not on integers, so the correct code is

```
isdigit(str[i]) == false
```

You're mixing up two different things, `isdigit(str[i])` tests if `str[i]` is a digit (i.e. `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'` etc) and `str[i] - '0'` converts the digit to a numeric value.

Comment: thank you so much! I edited my question to be more precisem, would you take a look please? I'm still confusing why my code didn't work since my interpretation is the same as yours.

Comment: @TommySUN Like I said this is wrong `if(isdigit(str[i]-'0')==false){` it should be `if(isdigit(str[i])==false){` Not sure what the confusion is.

Comment: @TommySUN Of course there could be many other reasons why your code doesn't work besides this one.

Comment: @TommySUN OK, looking at your code again, it's clear that you are mixing up strings and characters. `"42"` is a string, but `str[i]` is a character. `isdigit` and `str[i] - '0'` both work on characters but it seems you are trying to convert a whole string. You need the `stoi` function for that.

Comment: @TommySUN If you are trying to write your own version of atoi then you need to convert the string one digit at a time. You need to write a loop and do the appropriate math to calculate the converted value. It looks like all you've managed to do is convert the first digit, you need a loop to convert all the digits.

Comment: Thank you for replying me. I was debugging and when I tried to convert the first character, it exit this loop. So I put a return inside this condition to see why this would let my program quit, and this quit with output 4. So the expected condition is isdigit(4) returns true and goes to the next for loop. But here, isdigit(4) returns false so ==false returns true. Which let the whole function return 4 immediately.

Comment: @TommySUN It's hard to help you with your code when I can't see the code. I suggest you post a new question and include more of the code you are trying to get help with. However `isdigit(4)` returns false but `isdigit('4')` returns true, that's how isdigit works. If you think you are seeing something else then you are making some mistake somewhere, but as I said unless I can see your code I can't tell you what that mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

`isdigit` takes int, which is char code and compares it to char codes of digit characters. In ASCII:

```
'0' - 48
'1' - 49
'2' - 50
'3' - 51
'4' - 52
'5' - 53
'6' - 54
'7' - 55
'8' - 56
'9' - 57
```

so if you take '4' - '0' for example you end up with 52 - 48 = 4. 4 is char code for EOT and is not a digit. You can see that it will never return true if your string consist of digits. It can return true if you use other chars in string, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main() 
{
    std::string str = "g";

    if (std::isdigit(str[0]-'0'))
        std::cout << "Success: " << int(str[0]-'0');
    else
        std::cout << "No cigar";
    return 0;
}
```

the result is 55, because 'g' is 103 and '0' is 48. 103 - 48 = 55 and 55 is char code for '7'

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. lets say str[i]='4'. Do you mean if I use isdigit(str[i]) then it will return true instead of using str[i]-'0'? Also I searched for char code definition online, but I didn't find its definition, could you explain a little bit more please?

Comment: Yes if you pass '4' to `isdigit` it will return true, because '4' translates to 52 and 52 is char code for digit '4', sorry if this is a little confusing. To see char codes for different characters you could use https://ascii.cl/